# MOSFET drain connected to case

Tags: mosfet

How can you tell from a datasheet if a MOSFET drain is connected to its case to improve thermal performance (for example where do I have to look at in the datasheet [here](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/308/FDP52N20_D-1808190.pdf) to ensure the drain and case are not connected electrically)?
I want to use a common heatsink for some power MOSFET but I don't want a short circuit between them.

Comment: Did you mean to ask how to tell if the drain is connected to the *case*? I can't imagine why they'd make a MOSFET with the drain connected to the *gate*.

Comment: Hah, I really cannot see anywhere in the datasheet that indicates what the tab is connected to. You can safely assume it's connected to pin 2 though; not sure I've ever seen a TO-220 made otherwise.

Comment: Even though it's most likely connected to drain...for situations like this it's best practice to not make assumptions so I would order a sample and buzz it out yourself.  There's a possibility it's not connected to anything.  OnSemi seems to sell MOSFETs with similar construction technology that come in TO-220 but with a plastic tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In discrete vertical MOSFETs, the chip substrate is electrically connected to the drain. "Vertical" means current goes through the chip vertically ; gate and source are on the top of the wafer, and drain is on the back. So when the chip is mounted in a package, the drain will be in contact with the metal piece that supports the back of the chip:

[image]

([pic source](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/leaflet/75016838.pdf)) That was a DPAK, here's a TO-220:

[image]

So, for vertical FETs, the tab is always the drain, and since the center pin is usually connected to the tab due to how the leadframe is manufactured, this means the center pin and the tab are part of the same chunk of copper.

Sometimes the datasheet will say otherwise: for example the tab may be isolated with a thin layer of plastic.

Lateral MOSFETs have the source on the back of the chip, so the tab and center pin are connected to the source.

For more complicated pinouts, like [these](https://www.eenewseurope.com/en/driving-down-the-on-resistance-of-silicon-carbide-transistors/), it will be mentioned in the datasheet.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. Seems like most power mosfet do indeed have a metal that supports the back of the chip which indicates the drain is connected to the case. Would the only option then be to use a thermal pad rather then screw in the mosfet into the heat sinks?

Comment: Yes, if you want insulation you can get an insulated mosfet (rare, expensive) or use mica washer+grease (cheap, effective, messy) or standard silpad (usually average thermal conduction) or Keratherm Red silpad (hard to get but excellent thermal conduction).

Comment: TO220 has a metal tab so you also need an insulating plastic washer or the screw will short it. TO247 has a plastic top, so you don't need the plastic washer, normal screw is OK. Or you can use clips to attach the device to heat sink, very convenient, no need to make hole in silpad, no risk of shorts with the screw, more uniform pressure, etc. Example image of clips > https://www.boydcorp.com/thermal/air-cooling/max-clip-system.html they're available from many manufacturers.

Comment: If your MOSFET dissipates just a few watts you can also use SMD, PCB as heatsink